# Autoloading a language

Tags: php, codeigniter, multilingual

In my autoload function I am trying to autoload a language, but I get this error:

```
Unable to load the requested language file: language/english/russian_lang.php
```

I have an `english` and a `russian` folder in my `application` folder.

My autoload is:

```
$autoload['language'] = array('russian');
```

Calling this does yield the appropriate result:

```
$this->lang->load('russian', 'russian');
goodPrintOverlap($this->lang->line('hello')); //goodPrintOverlap is custom function
```

Does codeigniter look into the english folder by default? Because that what the error says.

Any help?

Comment: Yep, that was it. Thank you =) You can make it an answer.

Comment: We'll wait for a mod to mark it as such so we keep SO clean ;-)